# CrudRepository custom find by current timestamp

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, crud

I have table Bound

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "boundId", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long boundId;

@Column
@Basic
private Timestamp startTimeStamp;

@Column
@Basic
private Timestamp endTimeStamp;
```

And i created query :

```
public interface BoundsDataRepository extends CrudRepository<Bound, Long> {
   @Query("from Bound b where b.startTimeStamp s <=:currentTimeStamp and b.endTimeStamp e>=:currentTimeStamp")
   List<Bound> findByCurrentTimeStamp(Timestamp currentTimeStamp);
}
```

I's give me an error. How should I name this query and how can I resolve this question?

Thanks for help!

Comment: can you show us your error please

Comment: This is possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958203/how-to-write-a-custom-crudrepository-methodquery-to-filter-the-result-in-my-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have some problems in your query :

- You don't need to use alias in the columns names `b.endTimeStamp e`
- You use parameters `:currentTimeStamp` but you don't pass any one in the query

Your query should look like :

```
@Query("from Bound b where b.startTimeStamp <= :currentTimeStamp and "
        + "b.endTimeStamp >= :currentTimeStamp")
List<Bound> findByCurrentTimeStamp(@Param("currentTimeStamp") Timestamp currentTimeStamp);
```

Comment: Thanks! You save me!

Comment: When I was writing the comment, it says("you need to wait 7  min")). Have a nice day!